# How should I structure my modules in order to make use of hbsfy and browserify?

Tags: handlebars.js, browserify

I would like to use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and the [hbsfy](https://github.com/epeli/node-hbsfy) Handlebars transform to modularise the JavaScript in a web application I'm writing.

Using gulp, I set up tasks to run browserify and hbsfy to compile several js and hbs files into one using a source structure that grouped my modules:

```
/src
  - /javascript
    - app.js
    - /module-one
      - module-one.js
      - module-one.hbs
    - /moduleTwo
      - module-two.js
      - module-two.hbs
```

However this is problematic when referencing one module from another - requiring the use of brittle relative paths that would need updating if a module is moved or further nested.

substack wrote on [Avoiding ../../../../../../..](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#avoiding-) in his (great) browserify handbook. There, he suggests storing app modules in a directory under `node_modules`.

Happily I set about doing this, but quickly ran into issues with hbsfy no longer compiling my templates. According to the [docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformopts-tr), browserify will only transform top level files, and will only transform those in node_modules if the `global` option is set to `true`.

This fixed my problem, but the documentation states:

> Use global transforms cautiously and sparingly, since most of the time
>   an ordinary transform will suffice.

I don't believe my use case is unusual - should I be storing my modules in a different manner? Or am I missing a piece of the puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple example in hbsfy itself which might be helpful to you https://github.com/epeli/node-hbsfy/blob/master/example/index.js

It depends on what is the framework you are looking at, if you are doing angularjs, you can see an example in https://github.com/mallim/sbangular/blob/master/src/main/resources/js/login/LoginCtrl.js

In this case, the specific code will be as follows:

```
  app.run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('login.html', require('./login.html') );
  }]);
```

login.html is actually in the same folder as LoginCtrl.js

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your reply. It is interesting to see how other people approach this problem - the second link claims to have structured their modules in the approach described by [Adam R Deibert](http://ardeibert.com/modularizing-an-angularjs-app-with-browserify/). I think this component based approach would work pretty well so long as you didn't need to refer to a sub-module from another (where you would run into the ../../ problem again). Hard to say whether I prefer this approach or just using the global transform in browserify without trying both. Need more time to play around :)